# Unable to migrate RDS Postgres to AWS Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I created a snapshot of my RDS Postgres DB, and I am trying to use that snapshot to create an AWS Aurora DB using the `migrate snapshot` option in AWS console, however the option is disabled for me, and I can't understand why?
[image]
According to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-to-an-amazon-aurora-postgresql-instance-from-another-postgresql-source/) official AWS blog, I should be able to migrate my RDS postgres DB into Aurora DB using the `migrate snapshot` option.

I created this snapshot from a Postgres DB running on version `12.5`. I have created another snapshot from another Postgres DB running on version `9.6.20`, and I face the same issue there as well.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why your change can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`12.5` and `9.6.20` versions of PostgresSQL are **not supperted** by aurora. What is supported is listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.20180305.html).

Comment: I can't seem to upgrade my 9.6.20 postgres db to any version that is supported in that document. For example I can upgrade to 12.5, but not to 12.4, Or, I can upgrade to 10.15, but not to 10.14. This is very confusing and I can't make sense of it.

Comment: @Benjamin Your RDS are newer versions than what is in Aurora. You have to downgrade, not upgrade. I'm not sure if AWS allows for downgrades. If not, you have to "manually" migrate all your data to Aurora database.